# can an app get certified without supplying snapped and filled views

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I know with windows 8.1 the concept of snapped view is going to change but for Windows 8, is it required to implement both snap and filled view. If so can you please provide any link where its stated as requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx

says:

> 3.6 Your app must use the mechanisms provided by the system for those features that have them
>
> **Your app must support a snapped layout**. In landscape orientation, your app’s functions must be  fully accessible when the app’s display size is 1024 x 768. Your app must remain functional when  the customer snaps and unsnaps the app.

(emphasis added)

I have, however, seen several apps that just show very little/nothing when snapped.  For example, nextgen reader just shows an empty area (annoying!).  Even the windows store app doesnt' do anything but show its logo when snapped on win8.

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't have the bandwidth to create Snap view for your application. You can just add a new page(Snap View) which is loaded when the user snaps your app. This way your app will not break and you will pass the WACK as well. You can successfully release it into the store and then update the app with snap view in the later release.